# Bash loop ping successful

Tags: bash, shell, unix, while-loop, ping

I'm thinking that this needs to be changed to a while clause, at the moment it'll wait till all 10000 pings are done, I need it to return when the ping is successful. The program "say" is on OSX it makes the computer speak.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo begin ping
if ping -c 100000 8.8.8.8 | grep timeout;
then echo `say timeout`;
else echo `say the internet is back up`;
fi
```

OK I don't have rights to answer my own question so here's my answer for it after playing around:

Thanks, yeah I didn't know about $? until now. Anyway now I've gone and made this. I like that yours doesn't go forever but in my situation I didn't need it to stop until it's finished.

```
#!/bin/bash
intertube=0
echo "begin ping"
while [ $intertube -ne 1 ]; do
        ping -c 3 google.com
        if [ $? -eq  0 ]; then
                echo "ping success";
                say success
                intertube=1;
        else
                echo "fail ping"
        fi
done
echo "fin script"
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `ping`, but what are you trying to accomplish by `echo`ing “say”? Your introductory paragraph implies that you're trying to execute the `say` command, which isn’t going to happen if you just `echo` the word.

Comment: @Lawrence, those are _backticks,_ not quotes. They will execute the `say` command and echo its output.

Comment: Oops, missed that pretty badly; my apologies. Although I’m still not sure what’s being accomplished there; `say` never outputs anything to stdout.

Comment: There's no need for $? in your solution; if ping... works fine.  Also, you can avoid the extra variable by using break: while :; do if ping; then break; fi; done

Comment: See also: [ServerFault: How to ping in linux until host is known?](https://serverfault.com/questions/42021/how-to-ping-in-linux-until-host-is-known). This appears to have some very promising and short answers which work with Linux too (which is missing the convenient `-o` option), not just with MacOs which has that option.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You probably shouldn't rely on textual output of a command to decide this, *especially* when the `ping` command [gives you a perfectly good return value](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ping.8.html):

> The ping utility returns an exit status of zero if at least one response was heard from the specified host; a status of two if the transmission was successful but no responses were received; or another value from `<sysexits.h>` if an error occurred.

In other words, use something like:

```sh
((count = 60))                           # Maximum number to try.
while [[ $count -ne 0 ]] ; do
    ping -c 1 8.8.8.8                    # Try once.
    rc=$?
    if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]] ; then
        ((count = 1))                    # If okay, flag loop exit.
    else
        sleep 1                          # Minimise network storm.
    fi
    ((count = count - 1))                # So we don't go forever.
done

if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]] ; then                # Make final determination.
    echo `say The internet is back up.`
else
    echo `say Timeout.`
fi
```

Comment: The count = 1 line should be ((count = 1)) to deal with the spaces.

Comment: @MSumulong, correct, it's hard to believe I (and everyone else) has missed that for the last three-odd years. Fixed up, and made all assignments to `count` consistent as well.

Comment: Using ping loops without wait/sleep by a non-admin user triggers flood prevention mechanism that causes inconsistent results. If you really intend to flood the network, then you might need to add `-A`

Answer (score 14):

You don't need to use echo or grep. You could do this:

```
ping -oc 100000 8.8.8.8 > /dev/null && say "up" || say "down"
```

Comment: This worked for me: ping -c 2 8.8.8.8 > /dev/null && echo "up" || echo "down"

Comment: The flag `-c 100000` means try `100000` times. With out this flag it will retry endlessly (you would need to interrupt it). Still because of `-o`it will return on the first successful ping.

Comment: This only works on OSX. Ping doesn't have the -o flag on windows or Linux.

Comment: Yes, tthe original question and this answer both assume macOS. Note that the point it to use the Mac's `say` command to report a successful ping. In the first comment under this answer, you'll see a variant for using `ps` and `echo` on linux.

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 18.04's `ping` doesn't have the `-o` option. Is there an equivalent for me?

Comment: I just asked here: [Unix & Linux: Equivalent of `ping -o` on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/678045/114401)

Answer (score 12):

This can also be done with a timeout:

```
# Ping until timeout or 1 successful packet
ping -w (timeout) -c 1
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: weird. It showed me "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Comment: @pupsozeyde That's because you shouldn't include the parenthesis, like so `ping -w 30 -c 1` for a timeout of 30 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the `-o` option, BSD `ping` (which is also on macOS) will exit after receiving one reply packet.

Further reading: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ping

**EDIT**: [paxdiablo makes a very good point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118948/bash-loop-ping-successful/6119043#6119043) about using `ping`’s exit status to your advantage. I would do something like:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'Begin ping'
if ping -oc 100000 8.8.8.8 > /dev/null; then
    echo $(say 'timeout')
else
    echo $(say 'the Internet is back up')
fi
```

`ping` will send up to 100,000 packets and then exit with a failure status—unless it receives one reply packet, in which case it exits with a success status. The `if` will then execute the appropriate statement.

**EDIT 2:** [Chris points out that my logic is reversed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118948/bash-loop-ping-successful/6119010#comment132460823_6119010), which is just embarrassing.  Additionally, the `echo` commands (inherited from the question) serve no purpose, and there's no need to require bash specifically.  I'm disappointed in 12-years-ago me.  Today I would write:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
if ping -oc 100000 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null; then
    say 'the Internet is back up'
else
    say timeout
fi
```

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 18.04's `ping` doesn't have the `-o` option. Is there an equivalent for me?

Comment: You have your code the wrong way round. This will say "timeout" when there is a connection (ping returns true) and "internet back up" when there is no connection (ping returns false).

Comment: @Chris Thanks, you're right. I don't have the slightest idea what I was thinking 12 years ago (!). My best guess is that I overlooked the fact that removing `grep` from the OP's first code snippet flips the exit status logic (and didn't bother testing ).

Answer (score 3):

I use this Bash script to test the internet status every minute on OSX

```
#address=192.168.1.99  # forced bad address for testing/debugging
address=23.208.224.170 # www.cisco.com
internet=1             # default to internet is up

while true;
do
    # %a  Day of Week, textual
    # %b  Month, textual, abbreviated
    # %d  Day, numeric
    # %r  Timestamp AM/PM
    echo -n $(date +"%a, %b %d, %r") "-- " 
    ping -c 1 ${address} > /tmp/ping.$
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        if [[ ${internet} -eq 1 ]]; then   # edge trigger -- was up now down
            echo -n $(say "Internet down") # OSX Text-to-Speech
            echo -n "Internet DOWN"
        else
            echo -n "... still down"
        fi
        internet=0
    else
        if [[ ${internet} -eq 0 ]]; then     # edge trigger -- was down now up
            echo -n $(say "Internet back up") # OSX Text-To-Speech
        fi
        internet=1
    fi   
    cat /tmp/ping.$ | head -2 | tail -1
    sleep 60 ; # sleep 60 seconds =1 min
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my one-liner solution:

```
screen -S internet-check -d -m -- bash -c 'while ! ping -c 1 google.com; do echo -; done; echo Google responding to ping | mail -s internet-back my-email@example.com'
```

This runs an infinite ping in a new screen session until there is a response, at which point it sends an e-mail to `my-email@example.com`. Useful in the age of e-mail sent to phones.

(You might want to check that `mail` is configured correctly by just running `echo test | mail -s test my-email@example.com` first. Of course you can do whatever you want from `done;` onwards, sound a bell, start a web browser, use your imagination.)

Answer (score 0):

I liked paxdiablo's script, but wanted a version that ran indefinitely. This version runs ping until a connection is established and then prints a message saying so.

```
echo "Testing..."

PING_CMD="ping -t 3 -c 1 google.com > /dev/null 2>&1"

eval $PING_CMD

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Already connected."
else
    echo -n "Waiting for connection..."

    while true; do
        eval $PING_CMD

        if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
            echo
            echo Connected.
            break
        else
            sleep 0.5
            echo -n .
        fi
    done
fi
```

I also have a [Gist of this script](https://gist.github.com/openjck/26c4ae8aa4cd035a92e36bd56093b37e) which I'll update with fixes and improvements as needed.